# DAO. How to create a "Recordset" with the latest record from a database table?

Tags: c#, dao

I try to do it with expressions:

```
 //  QUERY 
                 string query1 = "SELECT * "
                                + "FROM Url_tabl "
                                + "WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Url_tabl)";

                db.Execute(query1);
```

But the request does not work.
I tried for the test to check whether there is a connection to the database table.
To do this, use the expression:

```
string query1 = "delete from url_tabl";
```

This expression works.

To create a Recordset with the last entry from a database table, I tried several queries, but they do not work. 
I get an error:
- *"Cannot start a sample query."*

```
string query1 = "select top 1 * " 
                + "from url_tabl "
                + "order by id desc";

string query1 = "select max(id) " 
              + "from url_tabl ";

string query1 = "select * " 
                + "from url_tabl "
                + "where max(id)";

string query1 = "Select top 1 * "
              + "FROM Url_tabl "
              + "order by id desc";
```

"Recordset" I plan to use in this method.

```
public void TestDAOTransferToAccess()
        {
            try
            {

                DAO.DBEngine dbEngine = new DAO.DBEngine();                
                DAO.Database db = dbEngine.OpenDatabase(@"C:\db\db_test.accdb", false, false); // ++

                 //  QUERY 
                 string query1 = "SELECT * "
                                + "FROM Url_tabl "
                                + "WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Url_tabl)";

                db.Execute(query1); // Работает

                DAO.Recordset rs = db.OpenRecordset("Url_tabl");
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                rs.AddNew();

                rs.Fields["status_url"].Value = "status_url_" + i;
                rs.Fields["url"].Value = "status_url_" + i;

                  rs.Update();
                }


            rs.Close();
            db.Close();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

How to create a record with the latest record from a database table?

Comment: What requirement drives you to use DAO rather than classic ADO.NET objects or Entity Framework?

Comment: The query you execute with `db.Execute(query1)` and the recordset you open with `db.OpenRecordset("Url_tabl")` have *nothing* to do with each other. Did you know that? Also, for various reasons, the "latest" row and the row with the maximum ID number might not be the same row.

Comment: @Reza Aghaei   DAO works well with Access.

ADO consumes processor. "Entity" I do not own. Do you recommend using "Entity"?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' not
I thought: I will execute the query, select the last line and create a "Recordset" where there will be one row, and not the whole table.
How do I do the right thing?

PS
  I don't know programming well, so please make allowances for my incompetence